# installation of openbable

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install **openbable** on Ubuntu, but I am having problems.

The Ubuntu version I'm running apparently does not have any package for this application.

How can I install it? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a simple command to install package in ubuntu is `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`. Did you try something like `sudp apt-get install openbable`?

Comment: The package index says it's available for all current releases: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openbabel

Comment: Could just be a typo. Openbable -> openbabel.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you actually use? Isn’t it [EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life)?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Open Babel's site](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Category:Installation), there are a few nice ways to install.

### Snap package

This method works only on Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo snap install openbabel
   ```

The program can then be run in the terminal with `openbabel.obabel` or, for other Open Babel commands, `openbabel.[command]` (replace `[command]` with the Open Babel command).

### Binary package provided by Ubuntu

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openbabel
   ```

The program can then be run in the terminal with `obabel` or other Open Babel commands.